# Interpreting long 'Start' network timing on ajax call in IE11 dev tools

Tags: javascript, ajax

At seemingly random times, the app I work on takes several seconds to send an ajax call, and I'm having difficulty interpreting the data from the network tab in the debugger.

[image]

Basically the 'Start' takes somewhere between 4 and 12 seconds. If I look at the MSDN docs and the browser itsself it states: 'The time from when the request was initially created to when the request is sent.'

What does it mean?

- Is it the time between creating the xmlhttp variable and calling the send() method of the object? This is how I interpret "from created to sent". Which would imply that the issue is somewhere in the ajax request code.
- Or is it the time between the click on the GUI, which would call a bunch of functions, of which one would trigger the ajax call? Which would mean there's a big delay between the event handler and the calling of the ajax function.
- Am I running into browser request queue limits due to making alot of requests? If this could be a problem, any tips on how to check this?
- Anything else?

I'll include the current code making the ajax calls in case option 1 is correct and something is wrong with the ajax function.

```
function get( path ) {
    var xmlhttp = null,
        domainRequest = false,
        handler,
        queryName,
        result = {};
    if (path.charAt(0) === '/') path = this.host + path;
    // Implicit resource name, get from path.
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        queryName = path.substring(7).split('/')[1];
        handler = arguments[1];
    }
    // Explicit resource name or alias.
    else if (arguments.length === 3) {
        queryName = arguments[1];
        handler = arguments[2];
    }
    result[queryName] = {
        "value" : null,
        "info" : {
            "filtered" : false,
            "query" : queryName,
            "server" : false,
            "status" : "ERROR",
            "message" : ""                      
        }
    };
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        var type = (domainRequest) ? 'text/plain' : xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'),
            response = (type === 'text/xml') ? xmlhttp.responseXML : xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (response) result[queryName] = response;
        else result[queryName].info.message = "Malformed data.";
        handler(result);
    };
    xmlhttp.onerror = function() {
        // Failure on the network level.
        if (window.navigator.onLine) result[queryName].info.message = "The requested resource could not be found or the service is down.";
        else result[queryName].info.message = "No network.";
        handler(result);
    };
    xmlhttp.open('GET', path);
    // CORS and IE10-IE11 withCredentials fix: the object state has to be OPEN to set the credentials flag in IE10-IE11
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;          
    // IE7-9 domain request premature abort fix.
    // http://cypressnorth.com/programming/internet-explorer-aborting-ajax-requests-fixed/
    xmlhttp.ontimeout = function() {
        result[queryName].info.message = "Network timeout.";
        handler(result);
    };
    xmlhttp.onabort = function() {
        result[queryName].info.message = "Request aborted.";
        handler(result);
    };
    xmlhttp.onprogress = function() {};
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `"Am I running into browser request queue limits"` How many calls are you making? How many other http requests are active?

Comment: @epascarello Usually only 4, chained together in a promise.all I don't think that's the issue, since this also occurs even if those requests are the only 4 and doesn't always happen when making 40+ requests. I just included it as one of the things I have looked into what could be the issue, but haven't found anything relevant or reproducable.

Comment: @Shilly if you ended up finding the root cause of this it would be great to know. We are experiencing similar behaviour.

Comment: @DylanLindgren I'm sorry, but we didn't find a specific solution to this. We changed alot to our mvc structure and the node.js backend by now. The only thing changed inside the ajax call is adding `xhr.navigationAbort = false;` but I can't actually find the docs anymore why we added that. :x We are experiencing less problems after the changes though, so the chance it was some part of code being very inefficient seems likely.

Comment: RIght, now that I think of it: One thing we Did change, was explicitly save all the xhr request objects inside an array and cancel them, if the end user navigates away from the state that made that request. So another option would be that we had 'pending' requests that didn't show up in the dev tools anymore, hogging resources.

Comment: Thanks for that. Very strange. I'm not sure if that's the case in our situation, but we will check it out!